# How do I make buttons import something?

Tags: button

I would like know how i could add a button that inserts things on html or php.

So here an example

Before I click the button
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg08R.png)

After I click the button
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p765o.png)

How do I do this?

Comment: you have to append text `<b> </b>` in textarea on click of button

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow  :) . Please post your code or whatever you tried so far for the question you asked. so that it will be easy for the users to give answers & resolve your issue.you cant give requirement direct without giving any efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do exactly like shown in image then try,

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
      var text = "> blockquote";
      $('#test2').append(text);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="test2">Hello world</textarea>
<button id="btn">
  click me
</button>
```